# Which implementation of OrderedDict should be used in python2.6?

Tags: python, dictionary, pep

As some of you may know in python2.7/3.2 we'll get OrderedDict with [PEP372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/) however one of the reason the PEP existed was because everyone did their own implementation and they were all sightly incompatible.

So which one of the 8 current implementations [in the PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/#reference-implementation) is backwards compatible with the 2.7 odict from python 2.7 in a way we can start using that now and depend on 2.7 in a couple of months?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just pull the code for OrderedDict from 2.7a4 into its own little module for now? It doesn't look terribly involved.

Comment: I'll have to try that, however note from the PEP there is a bug with the json module in py2.6 http://bugs.python.org/issue5381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict/1.1) (for Python 2.4 or better) claims to be "A drop-in substitute for Py2.7's new collections.OrderedDict that works in Python 2.4-2.6.", but I have not checked that claim.

Comment: ohhh I totally missed that in my search in pypi. I think I searched for odict and not ordereddict.

I'm pretty sure that one is the one as it's author is the same guy from the pep. I'll test it out and confirm here.