# Python 2.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

I am new to Python and am working on a Linux machine (Ubuntu 10.10). It is running python 2.6, but I'd like to run 2.7 as it has features I want to use. I have been urged to not install 2.7 and set that as my default python.

My question is, how can I install 2.7 and run it side by side with 2.6?

Answer (score 108):

I did it with [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew) on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
$ curl -kL https://raw.github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/master/pythonbrew-install | bash
$ . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
$ pythonbrew install 2.7.1
$ pythonbrew switch 2.7.1
Switched to Python-2.7.1
$ python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

[I also used it to install Python 3.2](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/02/what-no-new-version-of-ruby.html).

Comment: what  does the line . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc do?

Comment: also, should i not setup pythonbrew to always be useable? doesn't that mean i need to... um, do something? if i log out and log in again, my pythonbrew is forgotten about. i think that line above has something to do with it... but what?

Comment: You're right, that line sets up pythonbrew by running all the commands in that file. Just add that line to your .bashrc file so that it happens every time.

Comment: I agree, [pyenv works great](http://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2013/08/acme-envy.html)!

Comment: This really helped me too! Thanks

Answer (score 10):

I recently backported Python 2.7 to Debian squeeze. Since Ubuntu 10.10 is newer than Debian squeeze, if you can do it on squeeze, you can certainly do it on Ubuntu. I don't have access to a Ubuntu 10.10 system. If I set one up, I'll test on it, and update this answer. So, here instead is a brief sketch of what I did on Debian.

First, a general and obvious comment, but something that is easily overlooked. One should not take the listed build dependencies of a Debian package too seriously. They may be far more specific than needed. For example, software like Python, which is designed to be portable and run over a wide array of systems, is unlikely to build depend on very specific versions of software. The runtime dependencies can be adjusted as well, but this should be done with more caution. However, runtime dependencies are mostly generated dynamically based on software that is already on this system, so usually that is not a big issue.

```
apt-cache policy python2.7
python2.7:
  Installed: 2.7.2-8
  Candidate: 2.7.2-8
  Version table:
     2.7.2-12 0
         50 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
     2.7.2-8 0
         50 http://debian.csail.mit.edu/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.7.2-8 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Selecting the testing version we get

```
apt-get source python2.7=2.7.2-8
```

Looking at `debian/control`, we see the following build dependency lines.

Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 5), quilt, autoconf, libreadline-dev, libtinfo-dev, libncursesw5-dev (>= 5.3), tk8.5-dev, zlib1g-dev, blt-dev (>= 2.4z), libssl-dev, libexpat1-dev, sharutils, libbz2-dev, libbluetooth-dev [linux-any], locales [!armel !avr32 !hppa !ia64 !mipsel], libsqlite3-dev, libffi-dev (>= 3.0.5), mime-support, libgpm2 [linux-any], netbase, lsb-release, bzip2, libdb4.8-dev, gdb, python, help2man
Build-Depends-Indep: python-sphinx
Build-Conflicts: tcl8.3-dev, tk8.3-dev, tcl8.4-dev, tk8.4-dev, python2.7-xml, python-xml, autoconf2.13, libncurses5-dev

Most of this is easily satisfied on squeeze. With the handy utility [`apt-show-versions`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/apt-show-versions) we get on my machine

```
apt-show-versions debhelper quilt autoconf libreadline-dev libtinfo-dev libncursesw5-dev tk8.5-dev zlib1g-dev blt-dev \
libssl-dev libexpat1-dev sharutils libbz2-dev libbluetooth-dev locales libsqlite3-dev \
libffi-dev mime-support libgpm2 netbase lsb-release bzip2 libdb4.8-dev gdb python help2man python-sphinx

autoconf/squeeze uptodate 2.67-2
blt-dev/squeeze uptodate 2.4z-4.2
bzip2/squeeze uptodate 1.0.5-6
debhelper/squeeze-backports uptodate 8.9.13~bpo60+1
gdb/squeeze uptodate 7.0.1-2+b1
help2man/squeeze uptodate 1.38.2
libbluetooth-dev/squeeze uptodate 4.66-3
libbz2-dev/squeeze uptodate 1.0.5-6
libdb4.8-dev/squeeze uptodate 4.8.30-2
libexpat1-dev/squeeze uptodate 2.0.1-7
libffi-dev/squeeze uptodate 3.0.9-3
libgpm2/squeeze uptodate 1.20.4-3.3
libncursesw5-dev/squeeze uptodate 5.7+20100313-5
libreadline-dev/squeeze uptodate 6.1-3
libsqlite3-dev/squeeze uptodate 3.7.3-1
libssl-dev/squeeze uptodate 0.9.8o-4squeeze5
libtinfo-dev not installed
locales/squeeze uptodate 2.11.2-10
lsb-release/squeeze uptodate 3.2-23.2squeeze1
mime-support/squeeze uptodate 3.48-1
netbase/squeeze uptodate 4.45
python/squeeze uptodate 2.6.6-3+squeeze6
python-sphinx/squeeze-backports uptodate 1.0.8+dfsg-2~bpo60+1
quilt/squeeze uptodate 0.48-7
sharutils/squeeze uptodate 1:4.9-1
tk8.5-dev/squeeze uptodate 8.5.8-1
zlib1g-dev/squeeze uptodate 1:1.2.3.4.dfsg-3
```

We see that everything except `libtinfo-dev` is available in squeeze. I do have the squeeze backport versions of `debhelper` and `python-sphinx`, but both of these are also available for debian squeeze in versions satisfying the build requirements.

Observe also that I have libncurses5-dev installed

```
apt-show-versions libncurses5-dev

libncurses5-dev/squeeze uptodate 5.7+20100313-5
```

Both of these packages correspond to the source package `curses 5.7+20100313-5`. Observe that `libtinfo-dev` in fact replaces `libncurses5-dev`.

```
apt-cache show libtinfo-dev

Package: libtinfo-dev
Source: ncurses
Version: 5.9-4
Installed-Size: 279
Maintainer: Craig Small <csmall@debian.org>
Architecture: i386
Replaces: libncurses5-dev (<< 5.9-3)
Depends: libtinfo5 (= 5.9-4)
```

One would not expect python 2.7 to develop on such a specific version of curses, and in fact it doesn't. However, if you try to build the packages without satisfying the dependency you get

```
debuild -uc -us

dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libtinfo-dev
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Build conflicts: libncurses5-dev
debuild: fatal error at line 1289:
You do not appear to have all build dependencies properly met.
You can use mk-build-deps to generate a dummy package which
Depends on all the required packages, or you can install them
manually using dpkg or apt using the error messages just above
this message.
```

So, it is necessary to edit `debian/control`. Note that you also need to similarly edit the file `debian/control.in`, otherwise the `control`
file will be incorrectly regenerated from `control.in`. The simplest thing to do is just remove `libncurses5-dev`
from the `Build-Conflicts` line and `libtinfo-dev` from the `Build-Depends` line, and then run `debuild -uc -us`
again. If you are going to have this package installed alongside the standard default Python 2.6 packages on Debian squeeze, you
also need to remove the two lines

```
Conflicts: python-profiler (<= 2.7.1-2)
Replaces: python-profiler (<= 2.7.1-2)
```

Those lines are there because 2.7 includes the `python-profiler` functionality.
If 2.7 is the default python, then `python-profiler` is no longer necessary. 
However, if one is installing 2.7 as a non-default Python, that reasoning does not
apply, and `python-profiler` is still needed by 2.6.

This should build successfully, and result in the following list of binary packages.

```
ls -lah *.deb

-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 289K Jan 12 02:33 idle-python2.7_2.7.2-8_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 1.1M Jan 12 02:34 libpython2.7_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 2.5M Jan 12 02:34 python2.7_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff  12M Jan 12 02:34 python2.7-dbg_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 4.9M Jan 12 02:34 python2.7-dev_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 6.0M Jan 12 02:33 python2.7-doc_2.7.2-8_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 692K Jan 12 02:33 python2.7-examples_2.7.2-8_all.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 faheem staff 1.7M Jan 12 02:34 python2.7-minimal_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
```

Finally, one can install the binary packages with

```
dpkg -i python2.7-minimal_2.7.2-8_i386.deb python2.7_2.7.2-8_i386.deb python2.7-dev_2.7.2-8_i386.deb libpython2.7_2.7.2-8_i386.deb
```

Sometimes `dpkg` can be a little difficult about satisfying dependencies when they are all installed at once, so you might have to run `apt-get -f install` afterwards if you get dependency errors, or alternatively install the packages in smaller groups.

Comment: Have you packaged this python-2.7-squeeze port?

Comment: @qMax: I did build a package based on these comments, yes. But I haven't put it anywhere public.

Comment: If 2.7.1-8 would suffice, then it's easier. Get it from "deb-src [...snapshot.debian.org...](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20110520T212730Z/) testing main", apt-get build-dep python2.6, apt-get install libexpat1 libexpat-dev. And [pbuild](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PbuilderHowto) it for squeeze as is.

Answer (score 5):

Well if the only thing you need is argparse (saw that in one of your comments!) you could just do :

```
pip install argparse
```

This is not exactly an answer to the exact question :-) , but indeed if you are only missing a few feature, many 2.7 features actually come from independent projects and/or some compatibility packages can be found, eg:

- [argparse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse)
- [Which implementation of OrderedDict should be used in python2.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484046/which-implementation-of-ordereddict-should-be-used-in-python2-6) : [OrderedDict on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict/)
- you should be able to replace [memoryview](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-3137-the-memoryview-object) with [buffer](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html)

The list of [2.7 novelties](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html) is admittedly longer, but most of the other new features are probably not a big miss, and in exchange you do not mess around with multiple python installations on your box. Otherwise go with pythonbrew :-)

Answer (score 3):

ubuntu 12.04

Install dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Add the repo:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
```

Update the repo index:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Install Python 3.3:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3.3
```

ubuntu 12.04 > more

Installing the dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev
```

Download and compile python:

```
$ wget http://python.org/ftp/python/3.3.0/Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2

$ tar jxf ./Python-3.3.0.tar.bz2

$ cd ./Python-3.3.0

$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3.3

$ make && sudo make install
```

Some nice touches to install a py command by creating a symlink:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ ln -s /opt/python3.3/bin/python ~/bin/py
```

Answer (score 1):

Just download Python 2.7 from http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.1/ and build it.

Comment: thanks. I got that part, but my question is more about how to switch back and forth between the two versions. With ruby I use RVM to manage multiple Ruby versions. Is there an equivalent in Python, or it not necessary?

Comment: But use "make altinstall" instead of "make install".  "make install" will configure 2.7 to be the default version and you don't want that. "make altinstall" will leave the system Python alone and you'll just need to use "python2.7" to invoke it.

Comment: Yes, make altinstall is the way to go.

Comment: Hmm. You can't "just build it". You'll need the build dependencies. Try "aptitude build-dep python2.7" or if that doesn't work, "aptitude build-dep python2.6" before trying to build from source. If you don't, you'll be missing a lot of important libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to create distinct Python environments. Just being newsy, but what does Python 2.7 have that you need?

Comment: I want to work with argparse. I'm python newsy, but not dev newsy ;)

Comment: flags on regular expressions!

Comment: Flags were around before 2.7, AFAIK.

Comment: To create a new virtualenv you need to have a python installed on your system. If you have only 2.6 installed, you can't create a virtualenv with python 2.7 !

Comment: @PawelRoman no, but the OP says they've been advised not to make 2.7 their default Python. Can still install it without making it the default.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to install **[ActivePython](http://activestate.com/activepython/downloads)** if you do not want to compile things yourself. It includes a [binary package manager](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/) as well.