# pythonbrew no longer there

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, pythonbrew

so i installed pythonbrew on my  ubuntuo 11.04 the other day - yesterday, actually - and now i cannot "find" it. Where before i would switch to 2.7.2, now all my requests for pythonbrew end in errors -

```
 pythonbrew: command not found
```

What did i do wrong, and where is my pythonbrew?

```
which pythonbrew
```

doesn't return anything... was i meant to make pythonbrew some sort of startup thing?

ps if you haven't guessed already, I am *not* very familiar with unixy things, sorry if this is an obvi question.

UPDATE i installed pythonbrew as per this SO item: [Python 2.7 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233536/python-2-7-on-ubuntu)

UPDATE2 ok so i reinstalled pythonbrew as per that so link (ie i ran curl -kL http://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/raw/master/pythonbrew-install | bash
 from my / directory)

that went and told me it had installed pythonbrew to the /home/{loginname}/.pythonbrew directory

so i went *there* and then i ran the other line in that so link (i have nfi what this line does, but run it!) . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc

ok, and now pythonbrew is back and running. even better, virtualenv, which i'd installed via pip after installing pythonbrew is *also* back. i don't know what is going on, but apparently every time i log in i need to

1. go to  /home/{loginname}/.pythonbrew directory
2. run . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc

any ideas if ubuntu can do the above two steps on startup/login?

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
[[ -s $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
```

to the end of the .bashrc file in your /home/{loginname} directory, Linux will automatically source pythonbrew's bashrc (assuming your permissions are all correct).

After adding the new line to your .bashrc either run

```
source /home/{loginname}/.bashrc
```

or fire up a new terminal