# How to update python 2.6.5 to 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7, updates

I'm writing a program in python, which requires the use of the `Counter` function, which is not supported by python 2.6.5. So I have been trying to find a way to update my python interpreter to the next version, but I haven't found anything for ubuntu 10.04. Could anyone tell me how I can update python 2.6.5 to python 2.7?

Comment: *Or* you could use [this backport of `Counter`](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/).

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-10-04

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 2.7 on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233536/python-2-7-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/101595/66962) worked fine for me, and download the tarball from http://www.python.org/download/.

Comment: I think the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/deadsnakes) is probably a better option, especially if this question has to be asked at all.