# Python environment on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am not familiar with the linux system and I have already uninstalled Ubuntu 15.04 for 5 times due to improper operation. Please forgive it if my question is some kindly stupid or too easy for you because I really do not want to uninstall Ubuntu again.

There are few question I really need to make clear.

1) On Ubuntu 15.04, the default python is 2.7.9. Now I need to use jupyter notebook so that I choose to install Anaconda. The latest version of anaconda is for python 2.7.11. So do I need to update my default python version to 2.7.11 so that I can use jupyter notebook rightly? Because after I installed the Anaconda for python 2.7.11, the jupyter notebook could not new a python2 script. Hence should I turn to the Anaconda for python 2.7.9?

2) Questions about how to update the python version of Ubuntu exist a lot but I need to make sure what is the rightest and newest one because python is changing everyday.
In this stackoverflow question [The Python 2.7 on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233536/python-2-7-on-ubuntu), this method is recommended the most.

```
$ python -V
Python 2.6.6
$ curl -kL https://raw.github.com/utahta/pythonbrew/master/pythonbrew-    install | bash
$ . $HOME/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
$ pythonbrew install 2.7.1
$ pythonbrew switch 2.7.1
Switched to Python-2.7.1
$ python -V
Python 2.7.1
```

But I saw the comment "should probably use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) instead of pythonbrew". So, if I need to work on multi-python environment, is [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) the newest and most recommended one?

3) If I want to choose the easiest method so that I could use jupyter notebook rightly, is the anaconda for python 2.7.9 the most recommended choice?

Thank you all a lot!

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, Jupyter should work fine with Python 2.7.9 (or even better, Python 3.X). I would try [installing using pip](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#optional-for-experienced-python-developers-installing-jupyter-with-pip) rather than use anaconda, preferably use a virtual environment. If you are re-installing Ubuntu, why not use 16.04 (which is LTS) rather than 15.04?

Comment: Anaconda is a distribution of python. It comes with python itself. So, effectively you would have two versions of python installed if you installed anaconda.

Comment: Oh, it is because I need to build the caffe environment. In the tutorial I read, it uses the Ubuntu 15.04. I do not know whether changing the version influences or not.

Comment: My python teacher recommend us to use anaconda. My major is not computer science so that I think anaconda might be more suitable.

Comment: I will try installing using pip, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, what are you trying to do is to update Ubuntu's system package.

What I did in the past is I have downloaded newest python, compiled it on my own and then started virtualenv that was using this freshly compiled python. However this process is a bit cumbersome and error prone.

I checked pyenv and pyenv-virtualenv, I think you should try it ( especially later one).

However perhaps Anacodna will work with python 2.7.9 and there is no need to update anything? In general difference between version 2.7.11 and 2.7.9 should be very minor.

Comment: Oh, I will try the methods you mentioned above. Maybe by installing anaconda, there are two python versions, so I need to change some settings of the system.

Comment: Yeah, by using the `pyenv` (https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/), it is so easy to deal with the problem. I only need to enter the commands, `pyenv install anaconda-2.4.0` , `pyenv global anaconda-2.4.0` and `jupyter notebook`, things go all right.